Laravel Backpack: model through pivot table not saved in a MorphTo relationship
I replicated the Backpack Demo example to have a 1-N polymorphic relationship.
The CRUD select is rendered correctly and data are taken from the database, if there.
Though saving does not work and I guess backpack should automatically save the pivot table.
Here some informations:
Articles Schema
-id:integer
-title:string

ArticlePivots Schema
- id:integer
- topic_id:integer
- articlepivotable_id: integer
- articlepivotable_type: string

Topics Schema
- id: integer
- label: string

Article Model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphOne;

class Article extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
    ];

    public function articlepivot():MorphOne
    {
        return $this->morphOne(ArticlePivot::class, 'articlepivotable');
    }
}

ArticlePivot Model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;

class ArticlePivot extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'topic_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'topic_id' => 'integer',
    ];

    public function topic(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Topic::class);
    }

    public function articlepivotable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}


Topic Model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\SpatieTranslatable\HasTranslations;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany;

class Topic extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasTranslations;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'label',
        'slug',
        'parent_id',
        'depth',
        'lft',
        'lgt'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
    ];

    protected $translatable = ['label', 'slug'];

}


And finally the ArticleCrudController
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\ArticleRequest;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;


class ArticleCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\Article::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/article');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('article', 'articles');
        $this->crud->set('show.setFromDb', false);
    }

    protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setFromDb(); // set columns from db columns.

    }


    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(ArticleRequest::class);
        //CRUD::setFromDb(); // set fields from db columns.
        CRUD::field('title')->type('text');
        $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'title',
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Title'

        ]);
        $this->crud->addField([
                'label'     => "Topic",
                'name'  => 'articlepivot.topic',
            ]
        );

    }


    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }
}


The select (with all topics) is rendered in the CRUD panel, though the controller does not save any record in the pivot table.
The same exact example can be found in the Backpack Demo, under Monster panel (MorphOne through relationship under the Relations tab).
Demo saves correctly the record.

do you have access to all their premium packages ?? if not ,then you wont be able to use many features , one of them might be saving to pivot table. as they have written in a big note saying until and unless you have all their premium package you wont be able to use it.

First, I assume you have a pro license. Second, did you try this in a clean install? Demo is mostly to show features, but have many functions disable, because is a demo.
Let me know if this work for you with a clean install.
Cheers.

Yes, I have a pro license. Demo has many features disabled yes, but it saves that specific data. The code I posted is from a clean install

I am going to post this as an answer because I think there are some questions raised here that require further clarification.
Having access to premium packages has nothing to do with saving the relationships. All the code in https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD is MIT as per https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/main/LICENSE.md
The code to save the relationships is located in: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/016c8bc9540c4796f90898134ddd4b0ff2ab0f6b/src/app/Library/CrudPanel/Traits/Create.php#L104
You can follow the function calls etc if you want, there is nothing paid there.
What Backpack/PRO (the paid add-on) provides, is an interface and everything linked for you. If you are a savvy developer you 100% can do exactly the same we do in PRO and have a working Backpack installation.
Back to the question, and since you have backpack/pro I am 100% sure that there is a misconfiguration, or a bug :-) Let's figure it out.
Since the relation you want to use is working on demo, I would advise you to just copy the demo implementation of what you need (even if it's named planets, or monsters or wtv. :-) and then customize what is needed.
It's possible that your use case is not 100% what is on demo and we may find something broken. Sometimes it happens :-|
If that's the case you can open an issue on https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD and one of our team mates will take care of it.
I tend to say if it works on demo, usually is some small detail missing. Let me know what you have different than what is on demo, if there is an issue it must be laying there.
Cheers

Hi, actually the differences between my example and demo rely on naming only. Article, ArticlePivot and Topic are, on your demo, Monster, Sentiment and User. I re-checked several times and everything seems exactly the same.
Select is displayed and relation autodiscovery works because I can see Topics listed in the select on my Article CRUD form. The only issue is on saving. I don't think I have to override any method dealing with saving. First because it is not documented and second because the demo doesn't either. Thank you for your answer.
